# How do I reverse engineer these resource files into their original resource?

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool

I've been reverse engineering a .apk file with the intent of getting it to a project file, or as close as I can. This means that I'll have all the source code files and assets, etc.

After running apktool on the .apk I get the decoded XML etc., but within the /assets/bin/Data directory there are a bunch of files with encrypted names and no file extention. The apktool.yml file lists these all under "doNotCompress" along with resources.arsc.

How can I turn the stuff in /assets/bin/Data to whatever the original resource was, such as images, sounds, scripts, etc.? I know this .apk was made in Unity if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

Apktool will not help you past where you are trying to go. Sadly you will also struggle with Unity to get anything back to near original assets - its intended to not be that easy.

You can get close with something like https://github.com/Perfare/Il2CppDumper though. It works off the bundled compiled assets commonly found in mobile Unity games.